# How to change text file coding charset using java

Tags: java, character-encoding

As in subject. How to rewrite the file with different charset?

Where are can find available encodings - final static ints?

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, inputEncoding);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, outputEncoding);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(osw);

    String line = in.readLine();
    out.write(line);
```

Comment: [Supported Encodings in JDK 1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *As in subject. How to rewrite the file with different charset?*

I'm not sure why you asked this question as your code seems legit, although it copies only 1 line (and swallows newlines). I wouldn't have used `readLine()`, but just `read()` in a loop, maybe with a buffer. This way you copy everything without modifying/swallowing newlines.

---

> *Where are can find available encodings - final static ints?*

By [`Charset#availableCharsets()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#availableCharsets%28%29).

```
SortedMap<String, Charset> availableCharsets = Charset.availableCharsets();
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The supported encoding formats are specified in the JDK Documentation.

As per the conversion, you can use

- [Supported Encodings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)
- [Read Encoded Data](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/ReadFromUTF8.html)
- [Write Encoded Data](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/WriteToUTF8.html)
- [Converting between String of different character sets](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio.charset/ConvertChar.html)
- [List all available character set converters](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio.charset/ShowAll.html)